# GPU parallelization efficiency

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, vectorization, gpu

I originally submitted this task as a basic parallelization question which was answered by @Divakar. His work will be the basis of this follow up. He suggested that further speed-up could be gained by porting the code to calculate on a GPU instead. I've been researching this avenue and was able to improve the vectorized solution from a 15% speed up in my case over iterative loops to a 50% speed up. However, further tinkering hasn't led to many other improvements. My first concern is that the hardware is not particularly powerful enough but before our group can justify spending money on new hardware, we would like to see more efficiency from the code on our current setup:

```
XGPU = gpuArray(X);
YGPU = gpuArray(Y);
HGPU = gpuArray(H);
EGPU = gpuArray(E);

% Perform kron format elementwise multiplication betwen the first two dims
% of X and Y, keeping the third dim aligned and "pushing out" leftover dims
% from Y to the back
mults = bsxfun(@mtimes,permute(XGPU,[4,2,5,1,3]),permute(YGPU,[1,6,2,7,3,4,5]));
mults3D = reshape(mults,N2,N2,[]);
clear mults;
Emults3D = reshape(EGPU*reshape(mults3D,size(mults3D,1),[]),size(mults3D));

% Trace summations by using linear indices of diagonal on 3D slices in Emults3D
MN = N2;
idx = 1:MN+1:MN^2;
idx2D = bsxfun(@plus,idx(:),MN^2*(0:size(Emults3D,3)-1));
pr_sums = sum(Emults3D(idx2D),1);
clear Emults3D;
clear idx2D;

% Perform "M/pr" equivalent elementwise divisions and then use
% matrix-multiplication to reduce the iterative summations
Mp = bsxfun(@rdivide,mults3D,reshape(pr_sums,1,1,[]));
clear pr_sums;
clear mults3D;

outGPU = reshape(Mp,[],size(Mp,3))*reshape(permute(HGPU,[3,1,2]),[],1);
outGPU = reshape(outGPU,N2,N2)/(sum(sum(sum(HGPU))));

clear Mp;

out = gather(outGPU);
```

Some relevant information: X is a 3D MxMxN array. Y is a 5D MxNxNxPxP array. H is a 3D construction of 2D histogram slices of size MxPxP. E is a M^2xM^2 matrix boolean mask.

The calculations that are currently bottlenecks is the creation of Emults3D and the creation of Mp.

My questions are the following:

- Are there better ways to better handle GPU memory allocations? Even tests on far superior hardware with 4GB of VRAM can not complete calculations on the full scale and need to be truncated and trimmed.
- Would writing CUDA kernels improve parallelization and speed up and what computations should I target?
- What parts of those lines are actually slow: the reshapes or the multiplications/division? In either case, are there other parallelized alternatives such as pagefun or similar to reduce the computing time?

I will note that once the calculation algorithms are improved, I plan on utilizing gpuArray constructors to remove as many host->gpu transfers in the beginning. This would also include waiting to construct E and H until later in the code so that they don't waste precious VRAM space in the beginning.

Comment: On a broad level I would think because of those `permutes` that bring in heavy memory transfers for multi-dim arrays, a GPU with better memory bandwidth could help. So, I guess the newer ones could be nice. Also, those range arrays : `idx = 1:MN+1:MN^2;`, `0:size(Emults3D,3)-1`, etc. could be constructed [`directly on GPUs`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/establish-arrays-on-a-gpu.html).

Comment: I tried to avoid the double reshape in creating emults3d via pagefun but it seemed to result in a slower result. Is it possible to create a threaded kernel of the kron multiplication since it is overloaded to handle gpuarrays to avoid the permutations? Could doing the permutations on the host then transferring the result possibly alleviate the taxing part?

Comment: Can't answer the first part. On the second part, I would think doing permutations on the device would be better if it can accommodate the data.

Comment: With respect to your third question: try the profiler (`profile on` before run, `profile viewer` afterwards). If speed is really your main concern, then why would you rely on Matlab?

Comment: At this point it's due to its simple implementation of gpu computation. If matlab is going to limit our potential speed up, we may switch to C. But given my limited knowledge of actual CUDA programming only being remotely familiar with matlab's implementation, that's quite the project and I was hoping to achieve better than 2x speed over iterative loops first.

I had used the profiler briefly to at least extract the slow lines. I'll investigate farther by separating the reshapes and multiplication.